# How add array to redis?

Tags: php, redis

participants
    I use REDIS database and use PHP client http://rediska.geometria-lab.net/documentation/
    Here i found type Sorted sets and try create users list for current user.
    My code is:

```
$sortedSet = new Rediska_Key_SortedSet('userslist'); // use collaction userslist
        $sortedSet[1] = array('name' => 'Max');
        $sortedSet[1] = array('name' => 'Vasile');
```

As I understand userslist indicates the name of the collection, and the number 1 in $ sortedSet [1] key. Then, in the console through the client redis-cli write:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SMEMBERS 1: userslist 
(empty list or set) 
and get a empty blank ... prompt, what am I doing wrong? May be my concept is wrong?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorted set commands is prefixed with Z.

http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set

Try:

```
ZRANGE userslist 0 -1
```

Answer (score 0):

SMEMBERS is set not SORTED SETS for sorted sets USE ZSETS

```
 ZADD myzset 3 "two"
 ZRANGE myzset 0 -1 WITHSCORES
```

ZADD expects 3 parameters key, score and member, You are not providing it in your code

```
ZADD myzset 1 "one"
ZADD myzset 1 "uno"
```

You will have to use ZRANGE to get the range from sorted sets

```
ZRANGE myzset 0 -1   // This will give all values in SETS
```

I do not know how the PHP library works but it seems you have overwriting the members

```
$sortedSet[1] = array('name' => 'Max');
$sortedSet[1] = array('name' => 'Vasile');
```

Use Monitor command on redis-cli it will help you to analyze which command redis is processing. So start redis-cli and type monitor and then run your script and check in redis-cli which command it is firing

```
redis-cli monitor
```

TIP: Try not to write any code until you understand how things works. E.g. In this case try to understand the difference between SETS and ZSETS